# Communication and sending big files over Websocket

Tags: node.js, rest, networking, go, websocket

I am buidling an App using Golang on server side and ReactNative/Node.js on client side.

A part of my app is to upload a video from the client to the server and to receive a video back (up to 100Mb).

As this is a bidirectionnal talk, I decided to use Websockets. This allow me to authenticate the user only once with its JWT Token and to keep the communication open up to the point where the client is uploading his video and receiving an other one in exchange.

Right now, I am at the point where I have to upload and download a video on both sides.
All the communicatio has been in JSON so far. The video can be sent like this:

```
//After a few messages
{ "type": "sending_file", "sha2": `checksumofthevideo`}
{ "type":"video_chunk", "id": 1, data=`someverylongbytesofdata `}
{ "type":"video_chunk", "id": 2, data=`someverylongbytesofdata `}
{ "type":"video_chunk", "id": 3, data=`someverylongbytesofdata `}
```

The server, at the end, concatenates and writes all the bytes into a file then verify the checksum to make sure it is correct.

I am concerned about the effectiveness of this approach. I read that I should have used POST instead, allowing a much easier conversation and big files handling with the server.

Also Websockets are great for being used in a browser but in this case, I am using directly a node.js server on the client side so I guess this is lowering the advantage of the websocket.

I am having a really hard time to decide which one (REST vs Websocket) to use. 
I would appreciate any help about this, thanks!

Comment: Websockets support binary data, have you tried sending binary data as-is instead of JSON with base64 or otherwise *encoded* binary data?

Comment: Uploading is usually one way. Describe the bidirectional aspects of the problem. Also, describe why you don't want to authenticate multiple times.  Is it that the files are tiny relative to the size of the auth tokens?

Comment: @mscdex : No but I need to be able to detect easily if the received data is binary also and I am not sure how to do this since all the other messages are starting by a standardized json parsing? 
I am using `ReadMessage() (messageType int, p []byte, err error)` to read from the websocket.

Comment: @Mellow Marmot: It is bidirectionnal from a user point of view: you upload a video and you receive one or more videos in return as a reward. There is no obligation of receiving one anyway (sometime there is 0, sometimes maybe 3). I would like to avoid authenticating multiple times because, caching appart, it asks to read from the AWS interface with a GET (http://somurl/.well-known.json), adding overhead, and do some crypto operations to verify the token which I assume can be heavy.

Comment: @Arkon The websocket spec has a packet field that determines the payload type, either text or binary. It's up to the websocket implementations to provide support for both types, so YMMV.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will finish my first working version of my app with websocket, writing down binary when I detect it and move to plain HTTP later then!